# Changing weekend definition

Tags: date-and-time

How to change the definition of 'Weekend' to get 'True' from every Friday from 22:00:01 to Sunday 23:00:00. Example:

```
DayMatchQ["03-Jan-2020 22:00:00", "Weekend"](*out: 'False'*)
DayMatchQ["03-Jan-2020 22:00:01", "Weekend"](*out: 'True'*)

DayMatchQ["05-Jan-2020 23:00:00", "Weekend"](*out: 'True'*)
DayMatchQ["05-Jan-2020 23:00:01", "Weekend"](*out: 'False'*)
```

r:)

Comment: `601200 >= Mod[AbsoluteTime[#], 604800] > 424800 &` ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a brief function that gives your desired output:

```
ClearAll[weekendQ]
weekendQ[date_] := 
 5 + 22/24 < DateValue[date, "ISOWeekDayExact"] <= 7 + 23/24

weekendQ["03-Jan-2020 22:00:00"](*out:'False'*)
weekendQ["03-Jan-2020 22:00:01"](*out:'True'*)

weekendQ["05-Jan-2020 23:00:00"](*out:'True'*)
weekendQ["05-Jan-2020 23:00:01"](*out:'False'*)
```